# MongoDb atlas only returning 1000 records

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, google-apps-script, mongodb-atlas

I'm working with mongodb atlas and apps script. I'm trying to pull all the records in the db with certain criteria (at present there are only about 1100). Up until recently I have been using the following code without problems:

```
var url = "https://us-east-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-wygci/endpoint/data/v1/action/find";
  var apiKey = "xxx";
  var authToken = "yyy";
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "*",
    "api-key": apiKey,
    "Authorization": authToken,
  };

  var payload = {
    "collection": "mycoll",
    "database": "mydata",
    "dataSource": "Cluster0",
    "filter": filterObj,
    "projection": {}

  };

  var options = {
    method: "post",
    headers: headers,
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    var result = response.getContentText();
    Logger.log(result);
  const myObjs = JSON.parse(result);
    Logger.log(myObjs.documents.length);

    return result;
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error: " + response.getResponseCode());
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    return false;
  }
```

This code works, but only exactly 1000 records are returned. I need the full 1100.

How can I get this working?

Comment: What is `UrlFetchApp.fetch`?

Comment: does the api return a nextpagetoken?

Comment: @Cooper, would that be in the returned json?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: search for Pagination in the mongoDB

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is a direct solution to your issue, in your script, when you add `limit: 1100` or `limit: 2000` like a large limit number in `payload`, what result will you obtain? [Ref](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/data-api/openapi/#operation/find) Unfortunately, the maximum value of `limit` cannot be found. So, I'm not sure whether a value of more than 1000 can be used. I apologize for this. So, I posted it as a comment. If this was not useful, I apologize.